# How to get text frames in MS Word document via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have large MS Word 2010 document that consists of data in "frames" at least that is what I believe it is. Here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of frame]

I tried this to access it:

```
Sub test()
Dim s As Shape
Dim i As Integer
Dim str As String
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    i = i + 1
    If s.TextFrame.HasText Then
        Application.StatusBar = i
    End If
Next s
MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

But it wouldn't get me there. I need to go through all these "frames", but again, I'm not even sure what it is, and dump it into Excel. Any pointers? I can extract the xml and parse it, but seems a bit overkill. (+ I'm not so good with parsing yet).

Comment: If you use Debug.print instead of Application.StatusBar, do you see a list of numbers in the VBA debugger? I wouldn't trust the status bar to always update as you'd hope.

Comment: hi @Christina - no, it seems that the if condition is never true. Which is weird, but only if I assume that these "boxes" or "frames" are part of the shapes collection. The bad part here is I cannot even tell what it is. It seems like frames are some sort of relic from earlier versions of Word and I don't know why anyone would use them. I think the file I am working with is a data dump from an old system.

Comment: Could they be content controls? It might be worth saving the doc to docx and extracting the xml. Maybe then you could tell what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I have *.rtf file with frames from Oracle Reports. Try my macro.

```
Sub test()
Dim TabHourFrames() As Variant
numb_frames = ActiveDocument.Frames.Count
    ReDim TabHourFrames(1 To numb_frames)
    counter = numb_frames
    For i = 1 To counter
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Frames.Item(i).Range
        t = myRange.Text
        TabHourFrames(i) = t
    Next i
 Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
        For q = 1 To counter
        last_par = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        Set rngLastParagraph = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(last_par).Range
            With rngLastParagraph
                    .InsertAfter Text:=TabHourFrames(q)
                    .InsertParagraphAfter
            End With
        Next q
ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
End Sub
```